# When to use `Math.sqrt` vs `**0.5`?

Tags: ruby, performance

In a back-of-the-envelope performance test in IRB in Ruby 2.1.4*, I noticed that `i**0.5` seems to perform a good deal faster than `Math.sqrt(i)`.

```
def benchmark(n, &block)
  start = Time.now
  (1..n).each(&block)
  Time.now - start
end
```

And the results:

```
benchmark(1_000_000) { |i| i**0.5 }
=> 0.101748

benchmark(1_000_000) { |i| Math.sqrt(i) }
=> 0.257887
```

---

1. In what cases should I use `Math.sqrt(i)` instead of `i**0.5`?
2. Is there a precision trade-off? (In particular, I noticed that `Math.sqrt(3015) != 3015**0.5`.)
3. Why isn't `Math.sqrt` just implemented as an exponent?

---

* In 2.3.0, this discrepancy seems to have gone away, and indeed `Math.sqrt` is about 30% faster.

Comment: I'd say unless you have a *very* good reason to use `**`, use `sqrt`, since it makes your intention clearer. I'd only go with exponentation if you profiled it and actually found that it's a bottleneck.

Comment: @Carcigenicate : what shouldn't be clear about `**0.5`?

Comment: @EricDuminil Not quite as clear as an explicit `sqrt`. If they perform equally (which seems to depend which version you're using), I'd say use the more explicit. That's just entirely my opinion though.

Comment: @PeterKagey: when 2 floats are separated by `7E-15`, you can probably consider them to be equal.

Comment: In Ruby 2.4 (using your benchmarks) `Math.sqrt` is consistently twice as fast.

Comment: @sagarpandya82: fruity indicates that **0.5 is 3x times faster than sqrt for Ruby 2.2, as fast for Ruby 2.3 and 10% faster for Ruby 2.4.

Comment: Note : This [commit](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/55473aea5c14316c11d6b66f5800f53c8aece8bb#diff-d0743de9937d80f18e5f272c7997ecf4L650) and this [benchmark](https://gist.github.com/jgaskins/2b680390cff632ad7b0c) might be of interest

Comment: @EricDuminil—for most cases that sort of difference isn't important, but it can affect round-tripping results, for example (which might be a more important design consideration for `Math.sqrt` than for `**0.5`.)

Comment: Since both are equally wrong, it won't matter so much. If you need precision you might as well keep `3015` as integer and `1/2` as rational.